# HDD S.M.A.R.T. information

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart, hard-drive-failure

Hello. Yesterday I was trying to install a program, when it got stuck. Afterwards, I saw a notice from Windows saying I should back up my data. I know if S.M.A.R.T. tells you something is wrong, then it's very bad news... I did some scans and found a very large number of bad sectors somewhere after the first half of the HDD. Can I do something to make it last for at least until summer, after I'm done with college? I really can't afford a new HDD.

[image: S.M.A.R.T. details]

Comment: Your hard drive has probably exhausted its supply of reserve sectors. Additionally, 12 more sectors are suspected to be faulty. It will die *very* soon. You should stop using it immediately until you have a large enough backup medium ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it starts to fail, it will never get any better - a hard drive will not "heal".

You backup & replace now, or one day your machine simply will not start & then you are in real trouble.

Attempting to 'patch' round a dying drive is the equivalent of taking your car to the mechanic to get the horn fixed...because your brakes failed.

Comment: I know it can't be healed, but I was hoping that I can isolate the second half of the HDD. Or a low-level format would help? I know that a HDD has spare sectors, and quite a few, like thousands of them.

Comment: Sure. You can put your finger in the dyke & hope for the best. Be sure to have a backup ready for when it does fail. Once Windows gets the red flag from SMART, it will simply refuse to even mount, let alone boot & then your only hope is to get the drive out & mount over USB instead, which ignores SMART, & see what you can scavenge of the remnants of your data.

Comment: @Peter There’s no such thing as a low-level format with modern (as in newer than the 90s) hard drives. Your drive has already remapped *32 400* sectors.

Comment: @Daniel B I just started a wipe of my HDD using Darin's Boot and Nuke. It's writing 0 to every sector it encounters. Was it a bad or good idea? Should I cancel this operation?

Comment: it won't make any difference at all, it will just be a slightly more wiped drive, security-wise, than a simple reformat & new mft. It won't extend its life, though may shorten it slightly [though as it's on its last legs anyway I wouldn't let that worry you ]